# Eliminate Excel Only "Got It" messages

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, office365

How do I stop all `Microsoft Excel` online "Got it" notifications?

Example showing Browse Version History "Got it" message.

[image: Browse Version History "Got it" message]

Clicking on `Got it` or the close button has the same effect, keeps coming back.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to turn off ScreenTips:

- Go to *File > Options > General*
- Under User Interface options, set "ScreenTip style:" to "Don't Show ScreenTips"
- Click OK.

If that doesn't work, you need a third-party program that will close these messages.
For example,
[ClickOff](http://johanneshuebner.com/quickcms/index.html%3Fde_downloads,2.html)
can be configured to close automatically a window while it's displayed on the
screen. (Don't worry, it can be set to English.)

Comment: Microsoft Excel Online does NOT have this option, only `Regional Format Settings`. You are thinking of the desktop application, not the online version accessible from OneDrive or microsoft365.com, etc.

Comment: Sorry not to have been of more help. I'll leave my answer here, in case it can help others.